# How do you convert a CASE WHEN & SUM in SQL to Linq To SQL

Tags: sql, linq

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    Group1 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group2 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group3 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group4 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group5 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group6 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group7 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group8 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Group9 = SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    (SELECT Age = DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE())
    FROM Person
    WHERE IsActive = 1) AgeGroup
```

What is the equivalent Linq To SQL statement?

**Edit 1:**

The nearest I can come up with is:

```
var ageGroup = Persons.Select(item => DateTime.Today.Year - item.BirthDate.Value.Year)
                    .Select(age => new {
                        Group1 = age >= 10 && age <= 19 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group2 = age >= 20 && age <= 29 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group3 = age >= 30 && age <= 39 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group4 = age >= 40 && age <= 49 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group5 = age >= 50 && age <= 59 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group6 = age >= 60 && age <= 69 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group7 = age >= 70 && age <= 79 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group8 = age >= 80 && age <= 89 ? 1 : 0,
                        Group9 = age >= 90 && age <= 99 ? 1 : 0
                    });

var summary = new {
                Group1 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group1),
                Group2 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group2),
                Group3 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group3),
                Group4 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group4),
                Group5 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group5),
                Group6 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group6),
                Group7 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group7),
                Group8 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group8),
                Group9 = ageGroup.Sum(item => item.Group9)
};
```

But this creates 9 SQL statements.

**Edit 2:**

Another way could be:

```
Persons.Select(item => DateTime.Today.Year - item.BirthDate.Value.Year)
    .Select(age => new {
        Group1 = age >= 10 && age <= 19 ? 1 : 0,
        Group2 = age >= 20 && age <= 29 ? 1 : 0,
        Group3 = age >= 30 && age <= 39 ? 1 : 0,
        Group4 = age >= 40 && age <= 49 ? 1 : 0,
        Group5 = age >= 50 && age <= 59 ? 1 : 0,
        Group6 = age >= 60 && age <= 69 ? 1 : 0,
        Group7 = age >= 70 && age <= 79 ? 1 : 0,
        Group8 = age >= 80 && age <= 89 ? 1 : 0,
        Group9 = age >= 90 && age <= 99 ? 1 : 0
    })
    .ToList()
    .Aggregate((previous, next) => new {
        Group1 = previous.Group1 + next.Group1,
        Group2 = previous.Group2 + next.Group2,
        Group3 = previous.Group3 + next.Group3,
        Group4 = previous.Group4 + next.Group4,
        Group5 = previous.Group5 + next.Group5,
        Group6 = previous.Group6 + next.Group6,
        Group7 = previous.Group7 + next.Group7,
        Group8 = previous.Group8 + next.Group8,
        Group9 = previous.Group9 + next.Group9
    });
```

But this retrieves the entire list to memory then computing the SUM of each column

Comment: Have a look at this article which might help you **http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/case-statement-equivalent-in-linq/**

Comment: It only answers the CASE WHEN part of my question but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to convert a perfectly good query to Linq2Sql?
It's most likely a waste of effort.

In this case, you're probably better off just executing the query and returning the results:

```
class AgeGroupResult
{
  public int Group1 { get; set; }
  public int Group2 { get; set; }
  // ... etc 
}
```

Then query the data context directly:

```
dataContext.ExecuteQuery<AgeGroupResult>( "... your SQL query ..." );
```

I think it's best to use an ORM (like Line2Sql) to manage your entities; the things you need to read / modify / write. If you need to extract data and have the SQL, why bother trying to convert that to a lambda expression.

**Update:**
I believe what you are actually trying to do is known as map/reduce, where you first extract (map) data and then reduce the data set by applying aggregate functions. In this case the mapping consists of calculating the age and the reduce stage is the application of the SUM function. Linq2Sql is great at implementing the *mapping* part, but it cannot deal with the *reduce* part.

Linq (not Linq2Sql) does support reducing through the Aggregate function but it operates in memory only. With the best case solution to this problem using Linq2Sql you get a set of integers from the database that you can reduce in memory.

Linq2Sql was not designed for this type of problem. You might be able to extend Linq2Sql to support this particular scenario, but again that's probably going to be a huge waste of effort.

So, in answer to your question: *there is no Linq2Sql equivalent for your query* if you require the results to be fetched from the database in a single SQL query and do not want any in-memory processing.

Comment: I just want to know if its possible.

Comment: I was thinking of extending the Aggregate function but too much work for nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking the following query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Group9
FROM
    (SELECT Age = DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE())
    FROM Person
    WHERE IsActive = 1) AgeGroup
```

is it what you were asking ?

Comment: Your answer is in fact a comment. Please use comments where appropriate

Comment: @LukasEder seems like it is another question :D

Comment: @huMptyduMpty .. please paste some solution also so that I can correct my answer and can improve my knowledge..

Comment: @pratikgarg : have a look at the article that I have put as a comment to the original question which explains how to use **case** in **linq**, also next time make sure where the **answers** needs to go and where the **comments** needs to go

Comment: @huMptyduMpty :- thanks for this article ... now I am getting my mistake .. :-|  in place of thinking about linq I was thinking about SQL(Oracle)..

Comment: That's why checked as useful comment.. :)